# sed task not working on macbook pro

Tags: sed, awk

I have not found a solution for the following stupid task.

I have a file whose complete path I denote with

```
file_name
```

and two strings which are stored in variables `var1` and `var2`.

I know that the string in `var2` is inside the file `file_name`. I want to find and replace all the occurrences of `var2` in `file_name` with the string in `var1`.

These strings contain path names. This means I have the character `/` inside.

Furthermore my machine is a macbook pro.

Combining many suggestions found on internet I finally tried in a terminal

```
sed -i "" -e "s:$var2:$var1:g" file_name
```

Result: file_name does not change. Any suggestion?

Is there a solution with awk?

Comment: Do either of var2 or var1 have a `:` in them? Does var2 have any regex metacharacters in it?

Comment: they have no :, this is the reason I choose :. But they contains spaces. Could it be a problem?

Comment: No. Spaces should not be a problem. But any of `*`, `+`, `^`, `$`, `.`, etc. could cause problems in `var2`.

Comment: do some small tests with inline code, i.e. `var1=a;var2=A;echo "Abc" | sed "s/$var2/$var1/"`. When that works, then make one change at a time until you get to your final working solution. What you have posted should work on the face of it. Oh wait, was file_name created on a windows machine? If so `dos2unix file_name` first. Good luck.

Comment: As per @hek2mgl's comment. What does happen when you run that command? An error from sed? Nothing? The file spit to the terminal?

Comment: As an alternative suggestion try dropping the blank `""` argument from `-i` and either giving `-i` a real extension or nothing.

Comment: @user65187 normally, your command should work, unless `$var2` or `$var` have something in it to cause it to fail. Please add some examples values of `$var2` and `$var1` that don't work for you. If the command gives an error, add that too.

Comment: Do you have write permission to `file_name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Macs use BSD `sed`, not GNU `sed`.  BSD `sed` does not have the `-i` or `--in-place` option.  You will have to write out to a temporary file, and then move the new file in place after it is written.